# how to prevent duplication in android listview in fragments?

Tags: android, android-listview

how could i prevent the duplication in ListView in android , even i clearList()?

I've tried to clear the list and notify the adapter

```
@Override
    public void clearList() {
        list.clear();
        searchAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

duplication in list items

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why do you think it is duplicating? Where is the adapter code?

Comment: it's duplicated onRefresh() , i think it's related to the contentView.